# How AirTime could change the look of the Facebook permission dialog?

Tags: css, facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-authentication

I saw this *very* personalized facebook dialog installing AirTime Facebook app:

[image: AirTime Facebook dialog]

1. How could they do that technically? (Just heavy CSS hacking?)
2. Is it against the Facebook's TOS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just a page that launches the dialog box, not the actual dialog (it's launched in a popup when you click the button) so it's still part of their site, on a page that detects if you've allowed the Facebook permissions.